# Как вывести категории в рекурсии от заданной?

Tags: php, рекурсия

Есть таблица.

id | parent_id | title |

id - это ид категории
parent_id - тут id той категории которой пренадлежит эта категория.

Как получить всех потомков от заданной категории? Я знаю что зесь нужна рекурсия но в php разбираюсь на уровне младенца.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Почему бы просто не написать простой запрос на WHERE. «Дай все, где парент_ид = нужному_ид.

Comment: В цикле бегать получается нужно.

Comment: Ну да, но это как просто.. Дайте запросу массив с ид и форычем пробегись